# Among all permutations $f$ of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, how many have $f(1)$ odd? $f(2)$ odd? Both odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Among all permutations $f$ of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, how many have $f(1)$ odd? $f(2)$ odd? Both odd?

I do not understand how to use the $f(1)$ or $f(2)$.  I get that a permutation is odd or even according to the number of transpositions that is made, but I do not get how to apply the $f(1)$ part.

Comment: For a permutation $f$ of the given set, it may mean that the value $f(1)$ is odd.

Comment: The question is not about the parity of the permutation. It is about the number of permutations with given parities at given indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If we need $f(1)$ to be odd, we have $(3)(4)(3)(2)(1)$ ways to create a permutation, because we are guaranteeing $f(1)$ to be $1$, $3$, or $5$. We then have $\boxed{72}$ permutations.

If we need $f(2)$ to be odd, we have $(3)(4)(3)(2)(1)$ ways, where we guarantee $f(2)$ to be $1$, $3$, or $5$, then build the rest of the permutation off of that. We also have $\boxed{72}$ permutations.

If we need both $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ to be odd, we have $(3)(2)(3)(2)(1)$ ways to create the permutation, because we guarantee $f(1)$ to be $1$, $3$, or $5$, and $f(2)$ to be one of the odds that isn't $f(1)$. We have $\boxed{36}$ permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Among all the $5!$ permutations, $\dfrac 35$ of them have an odd number in the first position, hence $72$. Same answer for the second position.

Among these, $\dfrac{3-1}{5-1}=\dfrac24$ of them have an odd number in the other position, hence $36$.

---

More explicitly:

The permutations that fulfill the first condition are

$$1\times\times\times\times,\\ 3\times\times\times\times,\\ 5\times\times\times\times$$ where the crosses denote the $24$ permutations of the remaining digits.

The permutations that fulfill the second condition are

$$\times\,1\times\times\times,\\ \times\,3\times\times\times,\\ \times\,5\times\times\times$$ also $3\times 24$.

The permutations that fulfill the third condition are

$$1\,3\,\times\times\times,\\1\,5\,\times\times\times,\\3\,1\,\times\times\times,\\3\,5\,\times\times\times,\\5\,1\,\times\times\times,\\5\,3\,\times\times\times$$

$6\times6$ of them.